How to associate a phone number with a flow
I have two resources in my CloudFormation template: flow and a phone number.
...

Flow:
    Type: AWS::Connect::ContactFlow
    Properties:
    ...
PhoneNumber:
    Type: AWS::Connect::PhoneNumber
    Properties:
      CountryCode: GB
      Type: DID
      TargetArn: !Ref AmzConnectInstance
      ...

How could I associate the phone number and the flow inside the template?
Important: I am not asking how to associate from the dashboard or using aws command line or via API or via SDK, etc. Only using the CloudFormation.

It doesn't look like it's supported by Cloudformation yet. You can create an issue here: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues
